# bitbake populate_sdk for image fails with error

Tags: yocto, bitbake

When bitbaking my image, there are no errors. However, when i want to run the `populate_sdk´ command for my image, an error occurs that i can't seem to figure out how to fix.

The error:

```
ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/yoctouser/build/tmp/work/poky-linux/myimage/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-get  install --force-yes --allow-unauthenticated 
(A_LOT_OF_LISTED_PACKAGES) returned 100:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 target-sdk-provides-dummy : Conflicts: coreutils
                             Conflicts: pkgconfig
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using the Poky Zeus.

When i google this error, I don't see any solutions at all.

Deleting the entire `/tmp/` folder does nothing and removing `coreutils` and `pkgconfig` only produces more errors. Cleaning sstate for the packages and for the images, doesn't have any effect either.

Any idea on how I can fix this problem?

Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Did you change the default of PACKAGE_CLASSES? What if you put it at the value 'package_ipk'?  It could be that package_deb is a bit less tested than rpm of ipk.

Comment: I put `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"` You don't think i can use debian package class when trying to run `populate_sdk`?

Comment: I would give it a try without overruling the default setting of PACKAGE_CLASSES.  It *could* solve this issue.

Comment: hmm, I will attempt to use `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"` and see what happens. I'll post the results. Ty

Comment: Or just without setting this and use the default of Yocto.  It is my guess ipk is more tested and used, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @vermaete Changing from `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"` to `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"` solved the problem. Thanks! Do you want to make it an answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `PACKAGE_CLASSES` to the default or `package_rpm` could solve your issue.
It looks like IPK and RPM are more used and tested that DEB.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-package_ipk
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-package_rpm